# Apache proxy rule config under authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I need to create a rule in my server that redirect two url traffic to another server just if the user is logged on my system (moodle).

I believe what I need is create a `proxyPass` and a `ProxyReverse` rule and a `rerwiteRule` rule that check is the user is logged. like above

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^(.*)subdomain/(.*)$" "/moodle/mod/plugin/authCheck.php?file=$1"  [L]

ProxyPass               /playback         https://remoteserver/playback
    ProxyPassReverse        /playback         https://remoteserver/playback

    ProxyPass               /presentation     https://remoteserver/presentation
    ProxyPassReverse        /presentation     https://remoteserver/presentation
```

But it is not working, it is even reaching the authentication code.

I appreciate any help, even comments can help it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
```

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond, the variable is set after a user is authenticated. This will work only with .htaccess/apache authentication methods I suppose.

I had a similar problem once, but I solved it with a php script where I could check if a user was logged in or not. A simple php *header* command (http://php.net/manual/pl/function.header.php) solved the redirection problem.